# Why does my if Else if statement not work in Batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

My Script

```
echo "Enter your choice (1 or 2 or 3) :"
set /p dbchoice=

IF %dbchoice EQU 1 ( 
    set dbtype="oracle"
) ELSE ( 
    IF %dbchoice EQU 2 ( 
        set dbtype="sqlserver" 
    )
) ELSE ( 
    IF %dbchoice EQU 3 ( 
        set dbtype="db2" 
    )
) ELSE (
    echo "Incorrect choice" 
)
```

I get the following output:

```
E:\csmilm>set /p dbchoice=
1
ELSE was unexpected at this time.
E:\csmilm>) ELSE (
E:\csmilm>
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: @tenfour: Check my partial output/ rather error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Closing brackets in the wrong place.
Try:

```
IF %dbchoice EQU 1 ( 
    set dbtype="oracle"
) ELSE ( 
    IF %dbchoice EQU 2 ( 
        set dbtype="sqlserver" 
    ) ELSE ( 
        IF %dbchoice EQU 3 ( 
            set dbtype="db2" 
        ) ELSE (
            echo "Incorrect choice" 
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: It gives me `E:\csmilm>set /p dbchoice= 1 E:\csmilm>IF dbchoice EQU 1 (set dbtype="oracle" ) ELSE (IF dbchoice EQU 2 (set dbtype="sqlserver" ) ELSE (IF dbchoice EQU 3 (set dbtype="db2" ) ELSE ( echo "Incorrect choice" goto end_java_version ) ) ) "Incorrect choice" E:\csmilm>endlocal`

Comment: windows batch file does not know anything about integers. try `if %dbchoice equ "1"`

Comment: Still does not work I added `IF %dbchoice EQU "1"` and even `IF %dbchoice == "1"`

Comment: @Adrien and ChrisBD: Also 1 more help, what if I want to check if something is `>= 5` how can I do that in batch script?

Comment: you type `help if` on a command-line and read the documentation. what you need is to replace `EQU` by `GEQ`.